# Tracking changes with $watch

Tags: vue.js

I'm experimenting with using 'watch', to track and act upon changes to a product object. Because I'm watching an object, rather than a simple string, say, I'm using the deep form:

```
    watch: {
        product:  {
            handler: function (val, oldVal) {
                console.log("Current = "+val.identifier);//example field
                console.log("Old = "+oldVal.identifier);
            },
            deep: true
        },
    },
```

Something is not quite right, though, because in this example, where I log changes to one of the fields, 'identifier', the old and new values are always the same (both show the correct current value).

What is it which triggers this change, and why might both values be the same?

Comment: Create an example either in a snippet or a plunker that demonstrates the behavior.  There isn't enough here to tell you anything constructive.

Comment: How are you changing the `product`, can you include that code as well where product is being changed.

Comment: Slightly complex to reproduce in an example. But simply put, I have a custom 'text-field' input component, used like this: `<text-field name="identifier" v-model="product.identifier" />`. The text-field component has an input tag, `<input :name='name' class='form-control' :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">`.  So it's simply using v-model, really. What I don't get is how the value can be the same, however it is updated. I thought the purpose of $watch was that it be called at the time of change, meaning the old and new values should always be different.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch):

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.